# Android:best way for send/get data from php

Tags: android, httpclient

i send and get data from php with this code

```
public void SendGetData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private InputStream is = null;
        private String url = "http://***/SendGet.php";
        private String page_output = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                    // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", ed_name.getText().toString()));
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            page_output = sb.toString();

            Log.i("LOG", "page_output --> " + page_output); ///<--------------------------|
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return page_output;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Log.i("LOG", " onPostExecute -> " + result );
            myJSON=result;
            Log.i("LOG", "myJSON" + myJSON);
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    Log.i("LOG", " GetDataJSON " );
    g.execute();
}
```

but most code deprecated like

> The type NameValuePair is deprecated
>
> The constructor BasicNameValuePair(String, String) is deprecated
>
> The type HttpPost is deprecated
>
> The type HttpEntity is deprecated
>
> The type HttpResponse is deprecated
>
> ...

What is the best alternative to the above method?

[OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Apache HttpComponents - HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) or is there a better way?

Thank you