# can use httpClient in Android Studio?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, httpclient

i use httpClient to send data to php file like this

php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['My_Data'];
?>
```

and i add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to AndroidManifest.xml for connect internet.

this is my main Activity

SendActivity.java

```
public class SendActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String myJSON;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send);

        SendData();
    }

    public void SendData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            private InputStream is = null;
            private String url = "http://----/send.php";
            private String page_output = "";

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                try {
                        // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("My_Data", "this is my data"));
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                page_output = sb.toString();

                Log.i("LOG", "page_output --> " + page_output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            return page_output;
        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                Log.i("LOG", " onPostExecute -> " + result );
                myJSON=result;
                Log.i("LOG", "myJSON" + myJSON);
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        Log.i("LOG", " GetDataJSON " );
        g.execute();
    }
}
```

i use Android Studio and Lots of code **deprecated** And my data not send to php and i can't get data from php

is httpClient Expired from Android Studio or I'm wrong?

Comment: i change data between php and android use httpClient with eclipse you can use another way [best way for send/get data from php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639439/androidbest-way-for-send-get-data-from-php) ,your code not wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Http client is deprecated in api level 22. So you must use open OpenUrlConnection. You can use this code

```
public class FetchUrl {

    private URL url;

    public String fetchUrl(String urlString, HashMap<String, String> values) {
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            Log.d("url string", urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(values));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                response = "";

                throw new Exception(responseCode + "");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        Log.d("query string", result.toString());
        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
  if (resEntity != null) {

  String response_From_Server = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
  Log.e("","response from server is : "+response_From_Server);
 }
```

Comment: what is `resEntity`?! `resEntity cannot be resolved to a variable`