# Retrieving Json object or String from a URL in android

Tags: android, json, httpclient, httpurlconnection

There are tons of tutorials on how to do this,BUT all have one problem,they all use httpclient or some other function or class which has been deprecated in the latest sdk's .Please can anybody post how to get a Json object or a string from a URL using the latest HttpUrlConnection . I have tried it but it didnt work.Please post the complete tutorial.
Example URL: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ranchi

Comment: You can use `volley`..!!

Comment: Can you please post the tutorial for it? I tried to read it from the android developers site but couldn't get it to run..

Comment: @ Gaurav Chaddha : Yeah sure..!!

Comment: @GauravChaddha, Other option is retrofit library http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/

Comment: you can do this with help of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652374/can-use-httpclient-in-android-studio/31653061#31653061)

Comment: @Gaurav Chaddha : Check below answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007406/4018207 ..!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Retrofit library provided by square [http://square.github.io/retrofit/](http://Documentation)

Here is a tutorial which has implemented Retrofit
[https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit](http://Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Below I have provided how to make a request open weather server using volley :

Add below dependencies to your gradle :

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

Method to get Current Weather data :

```
/**
     * To get current weather
     *
     * @param latitude        : a current latitude
     * @param longitude       : a current longitude
     */
    public void getCurrentWeatherData(double latitude, double longitude) {

    final String URL_CURRENT_WEATHER = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";
    final String WEATHER_API_KEY = "8bf8ba5fa2f008b8bdda9cded4edf109";
    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(URL_CURRENT_WEATHER).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("lat", String.valueOf(latitude))
            .appendQueryParameter("lon", String.valueOf(longitude))
            .appendQueryParameter("units", "metric")
            .appendQueryParameter("APPID", WEATHER_API_KEY).build();

    JsonObjectRequest registrationRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, builtUri.toString(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    Log.e(TAG, registrationRequest.getUrl());
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   queue.add(registrationRequest);
}
```

How to call this method :

```
  getCurrentWeatherData(27,72);
```

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the string of complete Json string

```
  public static String httpGet() throws IOException {
  URL url = http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ranchi
  HttpURLConnection conn =
  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
  throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
 }

// Buffer the result into a string
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line);
 }
 rd.close();

 conn.disconnect();
 return sb.toString();
 }
```

now you can create a json object from the string like

```
JSONObject jsonResponse =  new JSONObject(httpGet());
```

with the jsonResponse you can work accordingly whether there is an array or string or other json objects inside that jsonResponse.

Happy coding

Comment: for further query, feel free to ask. I will try to help you