# How do I change this code to make use of HttpURLConnection instead of httpClient

Tags: java, android

I know the HttpClient is depreceted and their alot of questions about an alternative. I have seen those questions and even read the documentation for HttpURLConnection. For the love of I cannot seem to get my code working with HttpUrlConnection. Are there any suggestions. Here is the code.

```
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ContentValues dataToSend =new ContentValues();
            dataToSend.put("name", user.name);
            dataToSend.put("uersname", user.username);
            dataToSend.put("password", user.password);
            dataToSend.put("age", user.age + "");

      //  URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.182.15/connection.php");
     //   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                + "Register.php");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams() {
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        return httpRequestParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallBack.done(null);
    }
```

Comment: This really isn't an answer to your question so I'll post this as a comment.

My suggestion is, don't use that! Use retrofit+rxandroid. It's better to get used to the proper library.

Check this http://blog.stablekernel.com/replace-asynctask-asynctaskloader-rx-observable-rxjava-android-patterns/

Comment: are you taking about JSONParser.java ??

Comment: take a look at a networking library like Volley or Retrofit, It will be a lot easier than it. Besides HttpClient and HttpUrlConnection will not be updated anymore. So My suggestion is don't use them.

Comment: you can use this code .I have already answered here [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652374/can-use-httpclient-in-android-studio/31653061#31653061)

Comment: i recommend you to use third party lib..like volley, retro...it will save number of lines of code and time also with a great performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this JSONParser class this is easy to use.

**JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String makeBufferCall(String serviceUrl) {
        Boolean registered = false;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        URL url = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

            url = new URL(serviceUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (status != 200) {
                throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
            }
            registered = true;

            // Get Response
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);

            }
            rd.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //ErrorLogger.writeLog(claimNo, "Error Msg : "+e.getMessage()+"..."+ErrorLogger.StackTraceToString(e), "sendSyncService Failed");
            //response.append("Error");
        }
        Log.v("Response:", response.toString());
        return response.toString();

    }


}
```

And use this class in AsyncTask using just calling the method. So don't need to whole code write in every time.

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Locate the Offer_POJO Class
            property_data = new ArrayList<Contract_POJO>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner
            property = new ArrayList<String>();

            JSONParser call = new JSONParser();
            jsonstr = call.makeBufferCall(url_property);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonstr);

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: This code works with a Register php file. So the JSON is not what I am looking for. I am looking for away to maintain the integrity of the code I posted as much as possible while using HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

**I am not run this code but I think it will work fine..**

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ContentValues dataToSend =new ContentValues();
        dataToSend.put("name", user.name);
        dataToSend.put("uersname", user.username);
        dataToSend.put("password", user.password);
        dataToSend.put("age", user.age + "");

        //  URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.182.15/connection.php");
        //   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

        try {
            URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.182.15/connection.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpMethod post = new PostMethod("SERVER_ADDRESS"+ "Register.php");

            post.setQueryString(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));

            client.executeMethod(post);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
    }
```