# How to use ThreadLocal for HttpUrlConnection/HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have org.apache Classes used for networking in my app. As it is deprecated now i want to use HttpUrlConnection and no 3rd party library. Main challenge i am facing is with ThreadLocal. I have a restclient which is using DefaultHttpClient and want to replace it with HttpUrlConnection as shown in below code

```
public static class UniqueHttpClient {

    private static ThreadLocal<DefaultHttpClient> uniquelocal =

    new ThreadLocal<DefaultHttpClient>() {

        @Override
        protected DefaultHttpClient initialValue() {

            BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams
                    .setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 90000);

            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 90000);

            DefaultHttpClient client;
            // registers schemes for both http and httpsb

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));

            KeyStore trustStore;

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

            try {

                trustStore = KeyStore
                        .getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

                trustStore.load(null, null);

                sslSocketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);

            } catch (Exception exEXCP) {

                exEXCP.printStackTrace();

                sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
            }

            sslSocketFactory
                    .setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));

            ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    httpParameters, registry);

            client = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, httpParameters);

            return client;
        }

    };

    public static DefaultHttpClient getUniqueHttpClient() {

        return uniquelocal.get();
    }

} // class UniqueHttpClient
```

If i try to replace DefaultHttpClient with HttpUrlConnection, how can i get the Url here to open the connection?

I have seen various posts related to ThreadLocal but i am not able to understand how i can pass url and return the client instance.

To clarify more i want to do something like this..

```
public static class UniqueHttpClient {

    private static ThreadLocal<HttpURLConnection> uniquelocal =

            new ThreadLocal<HttpURLConnection >() {

                @Override
                protected HttpURLConnection  initialValue() {

                    HttpURLConnection  urlConn = null;
                    try {
                        URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
                        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
                        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(90000);
                        urlConn.setReadTimeout(90000);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // registers schemes for both http and httpsb

                    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

                    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                            .getSocketFactory(), 80));

                    KeyStore trustStore;

                    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

                    try {

                        trustStore = KeyStore
                                .getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

                        trustStore.load(null, null);

                        sslSocketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);

                    } catch (Exception exEXCP) {

                        exEXCP.printStackTrace();

                        sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
                    }

                    sslSocketFactory
                            .setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));

                    //client = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, httpParameters);

                    return urlConn;
                }

            };
```

In the above code how i can get the url(requestUrl) from multiple clients so that i would be able to openConnection successfully and return the urlConn object. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use this code   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652374/can-use-httpclient-in-android-studio/31653061#31653061

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks for your response. My main problem is how i can use it in ThreadLocal. How i can pass the url to Threadlocal static class?

Comment: please see my answer i have given a demo and let me know result